# Get file size from folder by filter

Tags: vb.net, file, directoryinfo

I'm using vb.net.
I wanna ask how I can get the file size for each file by filter?
I wanna get all the size of .ts files

here's the code I'm using

```
Dim TotalSize As Long = 0
Sub FileSize()
    Dim TheSize As Long = GetDirSize(txtPath.Text)

    TotalSize = 0 'Reset the counter

    If TheSize < 1024 Then
        lblSize.Text = Math.Round(TheSize, 0) & " B"
    ElseIf TheSize > 1024 AndAlso TheSize < (1024 ^ 2) Then
        lblSize.Text = Math.Round(TheSize / 1024, 1) & " KB"
    ElseIf TheSize > (1024 ^ 2) AndAlso TheSize < (1024 ^ 3) Then
        lblSize.Text = Math.Round(TheSize / 1024 / 1024, 1) & " MB"
    ElseIf TheSize > (1024 ^ 3) AndAlso TheSize < (1024 ^ 4) Then
        lblSize.Text = Math.Round(TheSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 1) & " GB"
    End If
End Sub
Public Function GetDirSize(folder As String) As Long
    Dim FolderInfo = New DirectoryInfo(folder)
    For Each File In FolderInfo.GetFiles : TotalSize += File.Length
    Next
    For Each SubFolderInfo In FolderInfo.GetDirectories : GetDirSize(SubFolderInfo.FullName)
    Next
    Return TotalSize
End Function
```

Comment: If your question genuinely doesn't need answer then you should delete it. If it's worthy of an answer but you have provided it yourself, you should post an answer and accept it, not post a comment. That way everyone can see that the question has been answered without opening it and reading it first. That said, I'm not 100% sure that you won't need a specific number of reputation points to be able to do those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles) directly, specifying a filter [SearchOption.AllDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.searchoption) as option, so you'll parse all the sub-folders in the specified path.

.Net Core 2.1+ also has an [EnumerationOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions) class and a corresponding overload of `GetFiles()`. This class allows to collect more parameters related to the search to perform.

You can simplify a couple of things and use a method that accepts all the parameters needed to perform this action: a Control that will show the result, the Path to parse and the Filter to set (`"*.ts"` here, as this was the example you posted).

```
SetControlTextToFileSize(label1, "C:\SomePath", "*.ts")
```

Helper and worker methods:

```
Private Sub SetControlTextToFileSize(ctrl As Control, folderPath As String, filter As String)
    Dim symbols As String() = {"", "K", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E", "Z", "Y"}

    Dim fileSize As ULong = TotalFoldersFileSize(folderPath, filter)
    If fileSize > 0 Then
        Dim lnSizeBase = CInt(Math.Truncate(Math.Log(fileSize, 1024)))
        Dim symbol = symbols(lnSizeBase)
        ctrl.Text = $"{fileSize / Math.Pow(1024, lnSizeBase):N2} {symbol}B"
    Else
        ctrl.Text = "0.00 B"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function TotalFoldersFileSize(folder As String, pattern As String) As ULong
    Return CULng(New DirectoryInfo(folder).
        GetFiles(pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(Function(f) CULng(f.Length)))
End Function
```

The last method in its *extended* form, in case it's preferable:

```
Private Function TotalFoldersFileSize(folder As String, pattern As String) As ULong
    Dim totalSize As ULong

    Dim folderInfo = New DirectoryInfo(folder).GetFiles(pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each fInfo As FileInfo In folderInfo
        totalSize += CULng(fInfo.Length)
    Next
    Return totalSize
End Function
```