# How to get program to list results in GB or TB rather than bytes?

Tags: vb.net, console-application, msdn

I was experimenting with some code that I found from the MSDN at the following link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.driveformat?view=net-7.0

I am wondering how I can have the program list the results as GB or TB rather than in bytes?
While I know how to convert bytes to list results as GB successfully ( TotalFreeSpace / 2 ^ 30 ) I am having issues with the program successfully listing results as TB.

I understand that ( TotalFreeSpace / 2 ^ 40 ) **SHOULD** convert bytes to list results as TB successfully; however, I am unaware as to how to have the console application list both results as GB and TB rather than bytes.

The standard code is as follows.

```
 Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim allDrives() As DriveInfo = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
        Dim d As DriveInfo
        For Each d In allDrives

            Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name)
            Console.WriteLine("  Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType)
            If d.IsReady = True Then
                Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel)
                Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat)
                Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total available space: {0, 15} bytes",
                d.TotalFreeSpace)

                Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total size of drive: {0, 15} bytes ",
                d.TotalSize)

            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

While I understand that implementing the following changes will list results as GB successfully.

```
 Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim allDrives() As DriveInfo = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
        Dim d As DriveInfo
        For Each d In allDrives

            Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name)
            Console.WriteLine("  Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType)
            If d.IsReady = True Then
                Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel)
                Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat)
                Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total available space: {0, 15} bytes",
                d.TotalFreeSpace / 2 ^ 30)

                Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total size of drive: {0, 15} bytes ",
                d.TotalSize / 2 ^ 30)

            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

And Implementing the following changes should list results as TB successfully.

```
 Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim allDrives() As DriveInfo = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
        Dim d As DriveInfo
        For Each d In allDrives

            Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name)
            Console.WriteLine("  Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType)
            If d.IsReady = True Then
                Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel)
                Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat)
                Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total available space: {0, 15} bytes",
                d.TotalFreeSpace / 2 ^ 40)

                Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total size of drive: {0, 15} bytes ",
                d.TotalSize / 2 ^ 40)

            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

How can I have the program list the results in GB or TB rather than in bytes?  I have four drives and two are sized in GB and two are sized in TB.  How can I have those drives listed properly within the console application?  Also if possible how can I remove the decimal places to only contain two decimal places after the results (EX 2.14 TB.)?

Comment: You simply need to divide by 1024 the appropriate number of times. Don't do anything but divide by 1024 but do it multiple times if required. Only convert bytes to MB and MB to GB and so on.

Comment: Please don't submit your question if your choice formatting is a mess. There's a preview of your question provided for a reason.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I apologize for the formatting, I wasn't aware that it would not implement the imports and module etc. even though I did place it and include within the single quotation marks that the code is included in.  I do inspect the formatting throughly and you can refer back to my previous post to show I follow the format preview as I should.

Comment: @jmcilhinney unfortunately dividing by 1024 the appropriate number of times will not work in this instance as there is no specifying variable within the code to determine if the drive is either in GB or TB format.  The total available space and total free space variable results apply to all drives.

Comment: @jmcilhinney formatting has been updated for easier review.  Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70220967/10024425 (see method "MemorySize")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return KB, MB and GB from Bytes using a public function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367190/how-to-return-kb-mb-and-gb-from-bytes-using-a-public-function)

Comment: Slight side question but what exactly does  _if the drive is either in GB or TB format_ mean?  GB or TB etc are really just shorthand notation for large numbers of Bytes.  There is no format.  Are you meaning you want to evalue d.TotalSize to see if best represented as TB or GB?

Comment: The drive isn't in either format. You get a number of bytes and you just dividing by 1024 as long as the result is greater than 1 and then report that. If a drive is less than a terabyte in size then the result will be a number of gigabytes greater than 1. If the drive is at least a terabyte in size then the result will be a number of terabytes greater than 1.

Comment: See the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61833411/7444103) -- The main function is the `Dim lnSizeBase = CInt(Math.Truncate(Math.Log(fileSize, 1024)))` expression

Comment: @Hursey That is correct.  I do apologize as I should have omitted the format wording.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  I apologize as I was not clear or concise with how I worded the question yesterday.  I have revised the question to reflect what I am seeking.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to say thank you to everyone in helping me out with this.  After using @jmcilhinney's answer above and some conditional formatting I was able to get the program to list the results properly.

Below is the code I utilized to achieve the results I sought after, in the hope that it may help someone out in the future.

```
Class Test


    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim allDrives() As DriveInfo = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
        Dim d As DriveInfo
        For Each d In allDrives

            Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name)
            Console.WriteLine("  Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType)
            If d.IsReady = True And d.TotalSize < 1099511627776 Then
                Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel)
                Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat)


                Console.WriteLine(
            "  Total size of drive:   {0, 15} GB ",
            FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))


            ElseIf d.IsReady = True And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 Then
                Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel)
                Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat)



                Console.WriteLine(
            "  Total size of drive:   {0, 15} TB ",
            FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))
            End If

            If d.IsReady = True And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then



                Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total used space:      {0, 15} GB",
                FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))


            ElseIf d.IsReady = True And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then


                Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total used space:      {0, 15} TB",
                FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))
            End If


            If d.IsReady = True And d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then


                Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total available space: {0, 15} GB",
                FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))

            ElseIf d.IsReady = True And d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then



                Console.WriteLine(
            "  Total available space: {0, 15} TB",
            FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please note the the conversion is needed as the original code snippet that this is based off of is meant to retrieve drive information in bytes.

Original code can be found in the MSDN located in the hyperlink below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.driveformat?view=net-7.0

Thank everyone for their time and help regarding this question.  Hopefully this will benefit someone in the future.

Please note this was utilized in a Visual Basic Console Application.

Results are listed below:

[image: Console Application Results]